Positive terms diverge to infinity and negative terms diverge to negative infinity in a conditionally convergent series.
Let $\sum{a_k}$ be a conditionally convergent series. How would I prove that $S=\sum_{a_k \geq 0}a_k = \infty$ and $Q=\sum_{a_k \leq 0}a_k = -\infty$?
Here is what I have tried. If $S$ and $Q$ both converge to a value, then $\sum{a_k}$ would be absolutely convergent as $\sum{|a_k|} = S + (-Q)$. If $S$ converges, but $Q$ doesn't, I think I have to show that $\sum{a_k}$ doesn't even converge conditionally. I am stuck on that.
Since Q does not converge, there exists an $\varepsilon_1 > 0$ such that for all $N$, we have that there exist $n, m$ such that $n \geq m > N$ and $$\left|\sum_{k=m;a_k\leq0}^n{a_k}\right| \geq \varepsilon_1$$
Since $\sum{a_k}$ converges conditionally, we have that there exists an $N > 0$ such that $n \geq m > N$ implies $|\sum_{k=m}^n{a_k}| < \varepsilon_1$. Then, $$\left|\sum_{k=m}^n{a_k}\right|=\left|\sum_{k=m;a_k\geq0}^n{a_k}+\sum_{k=m;a_k\leq0}^n{a_k}\right| < \varepsilon_1$$
I am trying to find a contradiction here, and this is where I am stuck. The other answers to similar questions contain an explanation considering a clever manipulation of the sums, but I want to see if there is a way to do this with an $\varepsilon$ argument.
